# Item position in Gravity Search Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, search

According to this article titled [Efficient clustering in collaborative filtering recommender system: Hybrid method based on genetic algorithm and gravitational emulation local search algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330121501_Efficient_clustering_in_collaborative_filtering_recommender_system_Hybrid_method_based_on_genetic_algorithm_and_gravitational_emulation_local_search_algorithm/related)

This is a paragraph from the article

> The current solution is chosen randomly from among the set of
>   chromosomes with the lowest mass. Its space is an s-dimension space
>   that is equal to the maximum number of clusters in the chromosomes
>   transmitted to the GELS algorithm. The number of dimensions of the
>   place of each mass is equal to s and the mass position in each dimension
>   is measured by the items numbers in the cluster corresponding to that
>   dimension.

From item sets of

> O={O1, O2, O3, O4, O5}.

Assuming that i have the items clustered as:

> C={C1,C2,C1,C2,C2}

So based on that paragraph i encoded the solution as

> C={C<sub>1</sub>={O1, O3}, C<sub>2</sub>={O2, O4, O5}}

Am i doing this right ?

Now currently i'm having a problem with this part

> The current solution moves in accordance with its current location
>   and its new velocity in the dimension d, and is located in a new location
>   in the dimension d. In fact, the new velocity value is added to the
>   number value of all items in the dth cluster in the current solution

Suppose that i have a velocity value of 1
How do i add integer to a set of objects? (Ex: C<sub>2</sub>={O2, O4, O5})